# QGIS anno labels

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to copy and paste Anno Labels in QGIS?

I have a layer that contains Parking Restriction information e.g. No Waiting or Limited Waiting 1 hour Mon - Fri 9am - 10pm etc. There are lots of variations of these restrictions.

What I'm looking to do is label everything in a neat little rectangle (blue back ground, white text) but it seems that I can only do this manually by creating individual Anno Labels which I can't copy and paste!

Comment: Have you considered using the data driven label placement that the ABC label tool in QGIS offers?

Comment: I had a play with this but couldnt work out how to break the label into two or more lines of text.